# How to union two tables and remove duplicates with conditions using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say we have two tables - `A` and `B`, whose column keys are `country, name, age`. I want to create a union table from `A` and `B`, called `result`, such that in the `result` table will be all the unique pairs of country and name, with a preference to pair from `A`.

For example, assume this is table `A`:

```
val column = Seq("country","name", "age")
val A = Seq(("New York","Smith","10"),
      ("Washington","Rose","5"),
      ("Mexico","David","1"))
val aDF = A.toDF(column:_*)
aDF.show(false)

+----------+-----+---+
|country   |name |age|
+----------+-----+---+
|New York  |Smith|10 |
|Washington|Rose |5  |
|Mexico    |David|1  |
+----------+-----+---+
```

This is table `B`:

```
val B = Seq(("New York","Smith","5"),
    ("Florida","Smith","5"),
    ("Washington","Jef","5"),
    ("Russia","Boris","12"))

val bDF = B.toDF(column:_*)
bDF.show(false)

+----------+-----+---+
|country   |name |age|
+----------+-----+---+
|New York  |Smith|5  |.  // Should not be included in the result table
|Florida   |Smith|5  |
|Washington|Jef  |5  |
|Russia    |Boris|12 |
+----------+-----+---+
```

And the result table will be -

```
+----------+-----+---+
|country   |name |age|
+----------+-----+---+
|New York  |Smith|10 |  // <New York, Smith> contained in A and B - we take from A
|Washington|Rose |5  |. // Contained in A
|Mexico    |David|1  |. // Contained in A
|Florida   |Smith|5  |. // Contained in B
|Washington|Jef  |5  |. // Contained in B
|Russia    |Boris|12 |. // Contained in B
+----------+-----+---+
```

How can I do that with spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new column `source` with literal values `1` and `2` respectively in dataframes `aDF` and `bDF` before the union operation. Then, use this column for custom ordering to eliminate duplicate rows with `row_number` Window function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("country", "name").orderBy("source")

val result = aDF.withColumn("source", lit(1))
  .union(bDF.withColumn("source", lit(2)))
  .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
  .filter("rn = 1")
  .drop("rn", "source")

result.show

//+----------+-----+---+
//|   country| name|age|
//+----------+-----+---+
//|   Florida|Smith|  5|
//|Washington| Rose|  5|
//|    Mexico|David|  1|
//|Washington|  Jef|  5|
//|    Russia|Boris| 12|
//|  New York|Smith| 10|
//+----------+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Full join might be more efficient than `union + window`:

```
aDF.join(bDF, Seq("country", "name"), "full")
.withColumn("age", coalesce(aDF("age"), bDF("age")))
.drop(aDF("age")).drop(bDF("age"))
.show
```

Comment: Can you explain how it can be more efficient? afaik, this will depend on the data and you can't say join will perform better than window (and vice versa) in absolute.

Comment: Well, I am just going  by "gut feeling": fewer operations usually means more efficient: union is essentially the same thing  as full join, but then you have repartition, sort and filter on top of it ... gotta be more expensive, though I am no sure how significantly.

Comment: Don't be mistaken, union is not the same thing as full join... FYI, join operations can be very expensive especially when you have large data. "_fewer operations usually means more efficient_" agree, but in this case it's not correct, union is very fast with spark, the only comparison between your solution and mine is about window vs join, and you can't predict without knowing the data which one will be more efficient.

Comment: @blackbishop how is union cheaper than full join? Elaborate please. My thinking is union is merge + dedup. There are multiple ways to achieve that. For example, sort both tables, then merge, skipping duplicates. Full join could do the same thing, except adding the values for dups in the other column rather than skipping. If anything, it should be faster, because you don't really need tables fully sorted, just partitioned/grouped by the join columns. I could see this potentially getting expensive with complex join criteria, but if you are just joining on columns, it seems cheaper than union.

Comment: This is correct in SQL but spark does not dedup when using union. only merge. See [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union)

Comment: @blackbishop ok, but the your window/filter dedups. So, the point stands.

Comment: That's what I'm saying from the beginning actually :) You can also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62430518/1386551).