# replace or optimize the join in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this code

```
df= dataframe_input.withColumn('status_flights', F.when((F.col('WOW') == 0), 1).otherwise(0))
df = df.groupBy('Filename').agg(F.sum('status_flights').alias('status_flights'))
dataframe_input = dataframe_input.drop('status_flights').join(df, ['Filename'], 'Left')
dataframe_input = dataframe_input.filter(F.col('status_flights')>0)
```

The join here is not optimized is there any way we can replace the join because we are doing the join between the dataframe and itself (after a small enrichment)

Comment: you can do the aggregation with a window operation instead of the join

Comment: what if Filename has a very high cardinality so the window partitioned by filename may give us worse performance no ?

Comment: it should improve performance compared to the join in your case

Answer (score 0):

This has been answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430518/spark-window-aggregation-vs-group-by-join-performance):

> It depends on the data. More specifically here it depends on the
> cardinality of the name column. If the cardinality is small, the data
> will be small after the aggregation and the aggregated result can be
> broadcasted in the join. In that case, the join will be faster than
> the window. On the other hand, if the cardinality is big and the data
> is large after the aggregation, so the join will be planed with
> SortMergeJoin, using window will be more efficient.
>
> In the case of window we have 1 total shuffle + one sort. In the case
> of SortMergeJoin we have the same in the left branch (total shuffle +
> sort) plus additional reduced shuffle and sort in the right branch (by
> reduced I mean that the data is aggregated first). In the right branch
> of the join we have also additional scan over the data.
>
> Also, you can check my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EIzhRKpiM8&t=1459s) from the Spark Summit where I analyze
> similar example.
> user avatar David Vrba

Something that is reviewed in the video is looking at the spark plans.  This can be done by using `.explain()` on the query that you are running to see what it's actually doing.  This can take some time to learn how to read but really is valuable if you want to learn to optimize.  In general the guidance is, the less shuffles you can do that faster your code will run.  If you can change any shuffle into a map side join you will run faster. (This is highly dependent on your data fitting into memory)

One thing that isn't discussed in the above article is if you will regularly be running this report their may be value in materializing the groupBy you are doing to make it run faster.  This requires additional work on insert but will help you squeeze all the performance you can get out of the table.  In general the more data you can pre-chew into a useful reporting format the faster your query will run.